# Parse Xml from Msn Weather Api Jquery (Phonegap)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

am developing a weather app for android using phonegap and i've been trying to parse this response from the MSn weather api

```
http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?weadegreetype=f&weasearchstr=Lagos
```

I tried the following code but it deos not work.Please HElp!! -->Thanks

```
    $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url:"http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?weadegreetype=f&weasearchstr=Ilorin,  
    dataType: "xml",  
    success: parseXml 
   });
   function parseXml(xml) {  
        $(xml).find("forecast").each(function() {  
            $("body").append($(this).attr("skytextday") );  
                });  
        }  
      });
```

Comment: I tried it on all browsers too

Comment: Am still stuck!!...Please help.THanks :)